# Data binding without using spring taglib for a variable begining with underscore "_"

Tags: html, spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

My html is built without using the spring taglib and now I'd like to bind the parameters of the form to a object in my controller.
I have a problem binding attributes begining with underscore "_"

Currently my form looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test.form">
          <input type="text" name="_NumeroPage" />
      <input type="text" name="_Tri" />
      <input type="text" name="_SensTri" />
      <input type="text" name="codePays" />
</form>
```

The relevant part of my object is

```
Class TestForm{
private String _NumeroPage;
private String _Tri;
private String _SensTri;
private String codePays ;
// getter and setter
}
```

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/test","/test.form"})
public String paginerSequencesSuiviMulticanal(TestForm formulaire, Model model, HttpSession session){

        model.addAttribute("_NumeroPage", formulaire.get_NumeroPage());
        model.addAttribute("_Tri", formulaire.get_Tri());
        model.addAttribute("_SensTri", formulaire.get_SensTri());
        model.addAttribute("codePays", formulaire.getCodePays());

    return "/result";
}
```

How do I go about binding it. Currently the binding doesn't happen for _NumeroPage, _Tri, *SensTri but it does bind codePays. 
Is there a work around to bind attributes begining with underscore charactere "*"  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably dig down into the bean property accessor code in Spring and find out why this is (couldn't find anything in a cursory examination of code or documentation), but it seems a far easier solution would be to **not** use names with leading underscores in classes and fields involved in data binding.

Comment: I think i know the answer . it isbecause spring use underscore to bind chekbox http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag
" The checkbox tag follows the existing Spring convention of including a hidden parameter prefixed by an underscore ("_") for each checkbox.

Comment: The problem is i am working with an old project that have been migrated to spring . and there is too many variables with "_" to change.
In a perfect world i would never use "_" to name the begining of an attribute in java ^_^
I have to find a work around for this ...

Comment: You'll probably spend more time trying to hack around this than it will take you to just change all the field and get/set method names to conform to convention so I would just do it. Sure, it may be boring work but all decent IDE:s have refactoring support so you can easily rename methods and fields and the IDE will rename all occurrences automatically. In the end, you will have spent less time and you will have gotten better code. Don't do ugly hacks when you can refactor.

Answer (score -1):

You could try creating a custom subclass of [ServletRequestDataBinder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/ServletRequestDataBinder.html) that maps request parameters starting with underscores to fields with no underscores.  You would then have to the create a customized [ServletRequestDataBinderFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletRequestDataBinderFactory.html) to create a subclass of.  Next you'd need to create a custom subclass of [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) and register it with Spring MVC.  This would allow you to continue using underscores in the HTML without necessarily requiring underscores in your POJO field names.

Custom ServletRequestDataBinder:

```
public class MyCustomServletRequestDataBinder extends
  ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder {
  public MyCustomServletRequestDataBinder(Object target) {
    super(target);
  }

  public MyCustomServletRequestDataBinder(Object target, String objectName) {
    super(target, objectName);
  }

  @Override
  protected void addBindValues(MutablePropertyValues mpvs,
      ServletRequest request) {
    super.addBindValues(mpvs, request);

    addUnderscoreBindValues(mpvs, request);
  }

  protected void addUnderscoreBindValues(MutablePropertyValues mpvs,
      ServletRequest request) {
    // go through each parameter and check if it starts with an underscore (_)
    // if it starts with an underscore, add it to mpvs under the name without
    // the underscore
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()) {
      if (StringUtils.startsWith(entry.getKey(), "_")) {
        mpvs.add(StringUtils.removeStart(entry.getKey(), "_"), entry.getValue());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Custom ServletRequestDataBinderFactory:

```
public class MyCustomServletRequestDataBinderFactory extends
    ServletRequestDataBinderFactory {
  /**
   * Create a new instance.
   * @param binderMethods one or more {@code @InitBinder} methods
   * @param initializer provides global data binder initialization
   */
  public MyCustomServletRequestDataBinderFactory(
      List<InvocableHandlerMethod> binderMethods,
      WebBindingInitializer initializer) {
    super(binderMethods, initializer);
  }

  /**
   * Returns an instance of {@link MyCustomServletRequestDataBinder}.
   */
  @Override
  protected ServletRequestDataBinder createBinderInstance(Object target,
      String objectName, NativeWebRequest request) {
    return new MyCustomServletRequestDataBinder(target, objectName);
  }
}
```

Custom RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter extends
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter {
  public MyCustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc} Creates an instance of
   * {@link MyCustomServletRequestDataBinderFactory}.
   */
  @Override
  protected ServletRequestDataBinderFactory createDataBinderFactory(
      List<InvocableHandlerMethod> binderMethods) throws Exception {
    return new MyCustomServletRequestDataBinderFactory(binderMethods,
        getWebBindingInitializer());
  }
}
```

Then register the custom HandlerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@Import(ValidationConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ControllerScanMarker.class)
public class MyCustomHandlerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
  /**
   * {@inheritDoc} Returns the subclass
   * {@link MyCustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter} in place of the default
   * {@link RequestMappingHandlerAdapter}.
   */
  @Override
  @Bean
  public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
    ...
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = new MyCustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter();

    // set additional adapter fields here...
    ...
    return adapter;
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there may be an easier way to modify/add additional values during the default request parameter binding, but I can't remember where the other hook is.